# Can't disable magento 2 Cache

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish

I am using Varnish cache on Magento 2.1, and I need to disable the cache for upgrading purpose.

I go to System > Tools > Cache Management, and select all the cache types, and choose "disable" and submit.

But I this error error:

> Deployment config file env.php is not writable.

I tried to chmod app/etc/env.php and app/etc/config.php to writable (777), but still can't disable the cache.

Any idea why this is happening?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Command prompt with `php bin/magento cache:disable`

Comment: Yes, this is the workable way even if env.php still shows the above error

Comment: it got resolved when You additionally set the write permission for app/etc/config.php apart from the env.php file

Comment: does it work for you? as illustrated in the question, I tried to chmod app/etc/env.php and app/etc/config.php to writable (777), but still can't disable the cache.

Comment: Also make sure `env.php` and `config.php` are owned by the Magento file system owner, not by the web server user. (Both files should be owned by `<magento file system owner>:<web server group>`)

Comment: for apache, should it be www-data:www-data?